# In my mvc full calendar, events are not getting displayed

Tags: model-view-controller, fullcalendar

I am facing a problem in rendering events from a SQL Server database. All events are getting fetched using this code but not getting displayed in my calendar, so can anyone please help me?

.cshtml code:

```
 events: function(start, end, callback) {
                debugger;
                 var startdate=start.format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'),
                     enddate=end.format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'),
                     params={'start_time':startdate,'end_time':enddate};
                 $.ajax({

                type: 'GET',

                url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEvents","Base")',

                success: function (data) {
                        alert("hello");
                        }
            });
            }
            ,
```

my controller code:

```
public static List<Task_has_UsersModel> LoadAllTasks(double start, double end)
    {
        var fromDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);
        var toDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end);

        var sql = "SELECT * from task_has_users"; 
        var data = Database.Open("DefaultConnection").Query(sql);
        List<Task_has_UsersModel> result = new List<Task_has_UsersModel>(); 
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            Task_has_UsersModel model = new Task_has_UsersModel();
            model.Task_Id = Convert.ToInt32(item.Task_Id);
            model.Project_Id = Convert.ToInt32(item.Project_Id);
            model.start_time = item.start_time;
            model.end_time = item.end_time;
            result.Add(model);
        }
        return result;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetAllEvents(double start, double end)
    {
        var ApptListForDate = LoadAllTasks(start,end);
        var eventList = from e in ApptListForDate
                        select new
                        {
                           id=e.Task_Id,
                           name=e.Project_Id,
                           start=e.start_time.ToString(),
                           end=e.end_time.ToString(),
                           allDay=false,
                           color = "#008000",
                           //allDay=false,
                           className= "label-important" ,
                        };
        var rows = eventList.ToArray();
        return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }



    private static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
        {
            var origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp);
        }

    }
```

I have tried with (double start,double end ) still my events are not getting displayed in calendar

Comment: i have done this in mvc using  C#

Comment: I am not well versed in C# but it looks like your events **select new { ... }** does not include a **start** time field, which is required by fullcalendar. **title** and **start** are the minimum required fields for an [event object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/). Also, with events as a function you need to use the [callback](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) which your above code doesn't do?

Comment: Which version of FullCalendar are you using? In the success of your ajax call you only have an alert you don't actually have any code to add the events to the calendar.

Comment: thanks for your answer , I have solved the problem and now it is working perfectly ... here is my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Finally after 3 days of hard work , i have done this.... No need to write anything in events , just call a function , it will automatically appends the date range and all you are done................... thanks

.cshtml code:

```
events:'GetAllEvents', 


        eventLimit: 50,
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,  

       // timeFormat: 'hh:mm-h:mma ', 
        timeFormat: 'hh:mma ',  
         displayEventEnd : true,
```

my controller code:

```
public static List<Task_has_UsersModel> LoadAllTasks(string start, string       end,string uname)
{

    UsersContext db = new UsersContext(); 

    var uid = (from i in db.UserProfiles
               where i.UserName == uname
               select i.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
    int userId = Convert.ToInt32(uid);
   // var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    var sql = "SELECT * from task_has_users where UserId = " + userId;  
    var data = Database.Open("DefaultConnection").Query(sql); 

    List<Task_has_UsersModel> result = new List<Task_has_UsersModel>(); 
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        Task_has_UsersModel model = new Task_has_UsersModel();
        model.Task_Id = Convert.ToInt32(item.Task_Id);
        model.Project_Id = Convert.ToInt32(item.ProjectId);
      //  model.start_time = Convert.ToDateTime(item.start_time);
        model.start_time = (item.start_time).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
        model.end_time =  (item.end_time).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
        model.title = item.title;
        result.Add(model);
    }
    return result;
}
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetAllEvents(string start, string end)
{
    string uname = (Session["UserName"]).ToString();
    var ApptListForDate = LoadAllTasks(start,end,uname);
    var eventList = from e in ApptListForDate
                    select new
                    {
                       id=e.Task_Id,
                       title=e.title,
                       start=e.start_time,
                       end=e.end_time,
                       allDay=false,
                       color = "#008000",
                       //allDay=false,
                       className= "label-important" ,
                    };
    var rows = eventList.ToArray(); 

    return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

finally done